# For all $a, b \in R $ with $a \neq 0$, the equation $ax = b$ has a solution in$R$

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $R $  is a non zero ring.

How can we prove the following conditions are equivalent?

In Proof 2 to 3, how can we prove  from $ a R = R $  that the ring has identity?

> 1:  For all $a, b \in  R $ with $a \neq 0$, the equation $ax = b$ has a solution in$R$ .
>
> 2: $ R^{2} \neq 0$  and $ R$ has no right ideals other than $ 0$ and $R$.
>
> 3: $ R$ is a division ring.

Comment: To your "2 to 3" question, $a\in aR$ should give you some info. It just remains to show that whichever $x$ has $ax=a$ works for all other elements as well.

Answer (score 4):

The set of all elements $x$ such that $xR=0$ forms a right ideal of $R$.

By hypothesis it can't be all of $R$, so it is just $\{0\}$.

In other words, $xR=R$ for nonzero $x$.

Let $x$ be a nonzero element. Two observations:

1. The right annihilator of $x$ is a right ideal, and it can't be $R$, so it is zero. Therefore $x$ is left cancelable. (Notice this is true for any nonzero $x$.)
2. $xe=x$ for some $e$, and furthermore $xee=xe=x$. Canceling $x$ we find that $e^2=e$.

Using the $e$ above, we see that $ey=e^2y$ implies $y=ey$ for any $y\in R$, so $e$ is a left identity.

Finally, there's probably a shorter trick, but this one is the first that occurred to me:
$(y-ye)^2=y^2-y^2e-yey+yeye=y^2-y^2e-y^2+y^2e=0=(y-ye)0$. If $y-ye\neq0$, we could cancel it on the left, obtaining $y-ye=0$, a contradiction. Therefore $y-ye=0$, and $e$ is a right identity too.

Comment: @SlimWiz As the solution demonstrates in the first five lines "**every nonzero element is left cancellable**"

Answer (score 1):

We can start with $aR=R$.
So $\exists \,b\in R$ such that $ab=a$. We claim $b=1$.
$$r(a):=\{x\in R\,|\,ax=0\}$$
is a right ideal which you may verify.
Thus $r(a)=0$ or $R$.
Notice $b\notin r(a)$ and thus $r(a)=0$, justifying left cancellation of $a$.
Now see that $aba=aa$, so $ba=a$.
As $aR=R$, $\forall\, r\in R$, $\exists\, r'\in R$ such that $r=ar'$.
So $br=bar'=ar'=r$ and thus $b$ is a left identity.

We are left with proving  $b$ is also a right identity, i.e. $\forall \, x\in R$, $xb=x$.
We know $xba=xa$, so $$xbr=br\quad \forall \,r\in R$$ $$(xb-b)r=0$$ In fact, $(xb-b)Ra=0$. $$l(Ra):=\{r\in R\,|\,rr'a=0\quad \forall \,r'\in R\}$$
is always a two-sided ideal, which is also an easy exercise. Thus $l(Ra)=0$ or $R$.
The latter is impossible as $b(ba)=ba=a\neq 0$, so $b\notin l(Ra)$. Thus $l(Ra)=0$.
As  $xb-b\in l(Ra)$, $xb-b=0$ and $xb=b$.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry I missed that part. Your solution is nice :)

Comment: Thanks for updating

Answer (score -2):

If $aR = R$, $a$ is not zero, then $R$ has identity:
we recall from **rschwieb** that left cancellation is valid. Now:

1. $aR = R \implies ac = a$ for some $c \in R$
2. $cR = R \implies cb = a$ for some $b \in R$
3. Prove that $a = b$ and then $c$ will be our identity:

   $ab = acb = a(cb) = aa \implies b = a$,

   $ac = cb = ca = a \implies c$ is the identity.

Comment: You've shown that $c$ acts like an identity for $a$, but since $c$ initially depended on $a$ it is not clear yet that $c$ does the same for other elements of $R$.  This is still incomplete, although it is an interesting observation.

Comment: For example, (the following is not possible under the hypothesis above but, just to demonstrate) in a boolean rng, every element acts like an identity on itself, but sometimes even the whole rng does not have an identity: e.g. $\oplus_\mathbb N F_2$