# Show that a ring with only trivial right ideals is either a division ring or $|R|=p$ and $R^2=\{0\}$.

Tags: ring-theory

I have trouble with the following problem: Let $R$ be a ring (it doesn't necessarily have multiplicative identity). If the only **left** Ideals of $R$ are $(0)$ and itself then $R$ is a division ring or $|R|=p$ for some prime $p$ and $ab=0$ for all $a,b\in R$. I tried to prove that $R$ is a domain, because if that's true then I have an easy way of proving the exercise, but I don't know if it's true that $R$ is a domain

Comment: Non conmutative

Comment: You can use the edit button to edit your question.

Comment: Next time please try to make your title more descriptive, too. Ask yourself "if I were looking for my answer, would I search for this title if I were looking for the answer?" If the answer is "no" then you're doing titles wrong. Also, search for your questions first. If you don't find the duplicate and someone else does, don't worry about it, it happens. If you don't search first, well, you *should*.

Comment: If you need help showing it has identity, then you could [look at this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2504549/29335) along those lines.

Comment: Well, the question that supposedly has an answer isn't solved, it just gives a Hint

Comment: @Sebitas You're right, it's an imperfect duplicate. I'm once again stuck trying to find the right one... it has appeared many times on the site, but it proves elusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2504549/29335), it is a division ring if $R^2\neq\{0\}$.

If $ab=0$ for every $a,b\in R$, then it is a commutative ring, and the ideals are exactly the abelian subgroups of the underlying group.

Then ask yourself what simple abelian groups look like.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider these two cases

1. $R$ has multiplicative identity $\implies$ $R$ is division Ring (of course vice versa)
2. There is no multiplicative identity,

Let $a \in R, a\neq 0$.  $aR$ is a right ideal, hence  $aR=R$ or $aR=(0)$

Case 2.1:

If  $aR=0$ and $a\neq0$, then  $Y=\{x| xR=(0)\}$ is an ideal (hence right ideal).

Since, $ a\in Y \implies Y=R$,

Thus, $bR=(0), \: \:\forall b \in R \implies R^2 = (0)$

Consider for any $a \in R, a\neq 0$,

$$H = \{e^{(+)}\} \cup \{ ka \; | \; k \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\} \} ,$$
where $e^{(+)}$ is additive identity.

$H$ is a subgroup under addition and it is also an ideal. Since $H\neq (0)$, we have $H=R$

Now for any $a,b \in R, a\neq0, b\neq0 $, we have

$$b=k_1a \implies b = k_1 k_2b \implies nb = 0, \: n>0. $$

Then you can show that, $pa=0, \: \forall a \in R$ for some prime $p$. Thus $|R| = p$

Case 2.2:

If  $aR=R$, you can show that it contains multiplicative identity, hence contradiction.